# C: Passing struct by reference

Tags: c, reference

I've defined the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
    double salary;
} Employee;
```

I want to change the value of `salary`. I attempt to pass it by reference, but the value remains unchanged. Below is the code:

```
void raiseSalary (Employee* e, double newSalary) {
    Employee myEmployee = *e;
    myEmployee.salary = newSalary;
}
```

When I call this function, the `salary` remains unchanged. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're copying the employee.  C does not have pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're passing a pointer to the original, **but** then you create a copy of it:

```
Employee myEmployee =*e;
```

creates a copy.

```
e->salary = newSalary;
```

will do it. Or, **if you must** have an auxiliary variable for whatever reasons:

```
Employee* myEmployee =e;
Myemployee->salary= newSalary;
```

This way, both variables will point to the same object.

Comment: the dot should be replaced with ->

Comment: I'd add that C does not have pass by reference.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant I think (hope) he means it in the sense that you can change the original value.

Answer (score 3):

```
void raiseSalary(Employee* e, double newSalary){
    e->salary= newSalary;
    }
```

In your code you create a local copy of the struct and only this local copy is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have allocated memory at caller, it should be:

```
e->salary= newSalary;
```